# Why is my (Mistral) LLM (almost completely) stopping to learn on my synthetic data after the first epoch, yet not overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, overfitting, llm

I am creating synthetic task-oriented dialogs that are rather complex. Training and validation losses suggest that the model (almost completely) stops learning, but does not start overfitting:

[image: Train- & Validation-Loss]

How accurate is the finding (based on these training and validation losses) that the model stops learning (almost completely) and does not start overfitting?

If the findings are accurate, what could be the reasons for this?

I am asking for this to understand whether it would make sense to move towards the infinite data regime (as the generation of data are quite costly, even though they are artificial).